# Get name of concrete type in trait

Tags: rust, traits

I'm implementing the Debug trait on a trait. I'd like to be able to display the name of the concrete type that implements this particular instance of the trait.

```
trait Node {
    foo: String,
}
    
impl fmt::Debug for dyn Node {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let name = // get type name of self here
        write!(f, "The name: {}", name);
    }
}
```

I've read a number of posts about Any and downcasting and whatnot, but these solutions seem complex.

One possible solution is to add a method to the trait itself: `get_name() -> String`, and implement it for each struct individually. There has to be a simpler way, though.

Comment: Why you want to implement `Debug` for `dyn Node`, instead of implement `Debug` for every concrete type?

Comment: @PengGuanwen So I can implement it once instead of two dozen times.

Comment: @ccleve the right way to "implement it once instead of two dozen times" is to `impl<T: Node> fmt::Debug for T` at which point you can use [`std::any::type_name::<Self>()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/fn.type_name.html) to get the type name.

Answer (score 6):

We could add a `get_name` method to `Node` which returns whatever the name of `Self` is using `std::any::type_name::<Self>()`.

```
trait Node {
    fn get_name(&self) -> &'static str {
        return std::any::type_name::<Self>();
    }
}
```

Inside the `Debug` implementation we can call `self.get_name()`.

```
impl fmt::Debug for dyn Node {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let name = self.get_name();
        write!(f, "The name: {}", name)
    }
}
```

Printing a `dyn Node` instance will show the following result:

```
struct SomeStruct {}
impl Node for SomeStruct {} 

fn main() {
    let a: Box<dyn Node> = Box::new(SomeStruct {});

    println!("{:?}", a)
    // The name: playground::SomeStruct
}
```

---

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4d31bac2c26522a545d9f5ebec6b135a)

Comment: Note that, while this is not necessarily an issue, if you impl the trait for `dyn Trait` it'll not show the real type.